# Autocomplete Google places API not showing anything

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I'm looking for setting up an autocomplete google place widget.

I have an input type text with a "searchFieldText" id.

Here is my JS code :

```
var inputsec = document.getElementById('searchFieldText');
var options = {
    types: ['all']
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputsec, options);
```

It couldn't be simpler... But nothing happens.
Am i missing something ? Maybe a mandatory option ?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got this.

Simply by deleting the options parameter did the trick